# How to get from $E_8 \rightarrow E_7 \rightarrow E_6 \rightarrow ...$

Tags: terminology, group-theory

I read in section 2 of [this paper](http://epjc.epj.org/articles/epjc/abs/2014/05/10052_2013_Article_2712/10052_2013_Article_2712.html) :

> "There is a well-defined chain to descent from $E_8$ to smaller
>   groups by chopping off a node of the [Dynkin diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram)."

What exactly is here referring to here? What is this process called to descent from a group to smaller groups?

EDIT: Two further things:

- Firstly, I think chopping of a node is equivalent to replacing it with $U(1)$ and
- secondly, I now suspect that chopping of a node in a Dynkin diagram is equivalent to the process of symmetry breaking.

Any confirmation of this by someone familiar in this topics or some further reading suggestion would be awesome!

Comment: 1. This seems to be a pure math question. 2. [Descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_%28mathematics%29) is a general mathematical name for spaces (bundles) lying "over" other spaces, like the $E_{i+1}$ here lies over the $E_i$ (the maps are surjective because "chopping off" a node makes the group "smaller" in a certain sense).

Comment: @ACuriousMind No, I dont think so. The process of "chopping of nodes" is something physicists do and I'm trying to understand what physicists are exactly doing here. This is a very common thing in GUTs and String theories.

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238680/11127